# How can I reuse an intent in api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I need some help because I don't really understand the api.ai "context". I don't even know if the "context" solves the problem.

Let's say you have few follow-up intents, you start from one and have two paths which should intersect again in a point. I want to create only one intent for this intersection point (I want to have two parents for this intent). I don't want to create two identical intents, I want to reuse this intent.

Is that possible? I checked documentation, forums and even here I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. Understanding why it is yes is important for the longer answer.

Intents are not tied to a specific path - they are triggered when conditions are met. In the simplest form, those conditions are phrases that are spoken by the user. More complex conditions would include having specific actions triggered by the device (such as the welcome action) or specific contexts being active. You can combine these - if a phrase is said while contextA is active, one intent might fire, while if it is said if contextB is active, a different intent might fire. Intents list which contexts *must* be active to be triggered.

This leads to the longer answer: Yes. What you need to do is have each "branch" managed by a particular set of contexts, but the "join point" would not require either of these contexts.

So let's imagine that you're writing an action that lets you order a single item from an ice cream parlor. (A single item because I don't want to get into complexity of tracking the order, etc.) You could have the following intents:

- Welcome

  Triggered by: Welcome action

  Sends: "Welcome. Do you want an ice cream cone or a soda?
- icecream.start

  Triggered by: user saying "ice cream"

  Sends: Sounds good. What flavor?

  Sets context: ice_cream
- icecream.flavor

  Triggered by: context = ice_cream and the user giving a valid flavor (vanilla or chocolate)

  Sends: My favorite. What size?

  Sets context: ice_cream
- icecream.size

  triggered by: context = ice_cream and the user giving a valid size (kids, small, medium, or large)

  Sends "So you want a   ice cream cone, is that right?"

  Sets context: ordered
- soda.start

  triggered by: user saying "soda"

  Sends: I'm thirsty too. What kind?

  Sets context: soda
- soda.flavor

  Triggered by: context = soda and the user giving a valid soda

  Sends: Good choice. What size?

  Sets context: soda
- soda.size

  Triggered by: context = soda and the user giving a valid size (small, medium, large)

  Sends "So you want a  . Is that right?"

  Sets context: ordered
- order.placed

  Triggered by: user saying "yes" (confirming the order) and context is "ordered"

  Sends: "Do you want napkins?"

etc etc etc.

In this case, we can split into two paths (each with similar, but not identical, possible responses) and then come back together with the "ordered" context.

(I should add that this only really covers the basics about contexts. There is more to them, including the lifetime of a context, how to work with multiple contexts that are active, and attributes you can set in a context.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it is more clear now. I will try with just context and what user says without "follow-up". I see in JSON that an intent has the attribute "parent-id" and I think that only one is possible and I need two.

When I tested, the content was active and the user said the right word but the intent didn't triggered.

Comment: If you're still having problems, please update your question to include details, with screen captures of the Intents in api.ai if possible. If this has resolved your question, please accept and/or upvote.

Comment: I solved the problem, I put a custom context on both "paths" output (I didn't knew I can create a custom one) and I put the same context on the joining intent input. And I also found out that if you have two contexts, both of them need to be matched (it works like an AND operation).